# WP8 How do I begin a Storyboard that's defined in my ControlTemplate?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, resources, storyboard, controltemplate

I have a `ControlTemplate` that is used on 9 Buttons (a tic tac toe field in this case)
The purpose is to have an additional animation that turns a `Button` red after the game has ended. The Template is defined in App.xaml and used in Spiel.xaml.cs. The Buttons using this Template are created in the code, not using the Spiel.xaml file.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MatrixElement" TargetType="Button">
        <Border x:Name="MatrixElementBorder" BorderBrush="White" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="140" Height="140">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="MatrixElementBackgroundBrush" Color="LightBlue"/>
            </Border.Background>

            <Border.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="storyBoardOnWin">
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MatrixElementBorder"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)"
                        From="DarkBlue"
                        To="DarkRed"
                        Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </Border.Resources>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
    ...
</Application.Resources>
```

I can't find a way to access the storyBoardOnWin animation in my code.
I tried accessing it via `Application.Current.Resources["storyBoardOnWin"];`
but that returns a nullPointer. How can I access the Template's Resources in the code behind?

Comment: Where is the template defined? What file? Where in the file? Who owns the Resource?

Comment: the template is defined in the App.xaml as a child of `<Application.Resources>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is that you've marked the storyBoardOnWin property as a Key in the Border's Resources dictionary. If you marked is as a Name instead, it can be called directly in your codebehind.

In other words, you have this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="storyBoardOnWin">
```

You can do this instead:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="storyBoardOnWin">
```

and call it from the code behind just like so:

page.xaml.cs

```
...
storyBoardOnWin.Begin();
...
```

Hope that helps! I'm not sure how you're using the ControlTemplate i.e. if it's defined as a resource in its own file so if it is, this probably won't work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sadly that doesn't work. since it's inside a template, it wouldn't know which button to perform the storyboard-animation on either

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the resource, because it is not a resource of App.Resources. It is a resource of a control that is a resource of App.Resouces.

I'm guessing that you already have the button when you are trying to get the animation (maybe through a button click event or something) so try the following:

```
var border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(button,0);
var story = (Storyboard)border.Resources["storyBoardOnWin"];
```

Comment: yes, the Buttons are already created. GetChild doesnt work though, because the buttons do not have any children elements (GetChildrenCount returns 0)

Comment: I had the same issue, and after seeing this solution I was able to make the idea work. However, I did not use GetChild. Basically I set a breakpoint and inspected the appropriate Resources to discover where the Storyboard was placed. After that all I had to do was write: var story = (Storyboard)TheContainer.AGrid.Resources["myStoryboard"];  Also, note, you may need to add x:FieldModifier="public" to Storyboard xaml